# Is the RESET signal in this LCD required pull-up resistor?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, pullup

I'm designing a circuit which includes this [LCD display](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-C12832A1Z-FSW-FBW-3V3.pdf).
There is no information about an internal or external pull-up resistor for the RESET signal. the only thing that the datasheet says about the RESET signal is active LOW.

So, I wonder, what should I do?

What will happen if I'll put pull-up resistor when internal pull-up is presented?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally best to assume that there is no internal pullup if one is not specifically mentioned.  Adding an external pullup in addition to an internal one generally wont harm anything, the total pullup will simply be stronger than the internal pullup on its own, which may have some advantage in some situations.

In general, it's a good idea to make a provision for an external pullup, and then if you determine in testing that the external pullup is not required you can simply not fit it.